# Why does this Powershell function return more than just true/false?

Tags: powershell, scripting

```
Function lyncNotFocused {
  # We need to check if the Lync window (conversation?) has focus or not.
  $hwnd = [WhichWindowActive]::GetForegroundWindow()
  $proc = [IntPtr]::Zero
  [WhichProcessActive]::GetWindowThreadProcessId($hwnd, [ref] $proc);
  Write-Host "DEBUG: Focused - hwnd $hwnd, process $proc"

  if (Get-Process -ID $proc -ErrorAction "SilentlyContinue" | Where { $_ -notmatch "lync" }) { return $true }
  else { return $false }
}
```

It returns something like "12412 True" or "9867 False". Never just the plain boolean value. The numbers correspond to the PIDs I'm looking up, and it seems the Get-Process cmdlet is pooping the bed here. How do I get it to shut up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you need to do a `| out-null` on the `[WhichProcessActive]` line of code.  It's probably returning the PID as well as setting it in the parameter.

PowerShell will send everything down the pipeline so unless you assign a method return value to a variable, or discard it with either `[void]` or `Out-Null`, it will also be returned.

Comment: Thanks @Andy...I should have added some more explanation like that.